# Form closing Event in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Just wanted to ask, Is there a form_closing event equivalent in VB6? (.bas). the reason I ask is that I wanted to prevent first closing the application if there's an open sub-window.

something like this.

```
Private Sub MainForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

  If hasSubWindow Then
    MessageBox.Show("You currently have active sub-window(s)")
    e.Cancel = false
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you use the `QueryUnload` or `Unload` events for that.

Comment: Yes you do, but the code in the above question is vb.net not vb6. See https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson6/p5.html for the sequence of events in vb6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three events: `Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)`, `Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)` and `Form_Terminate()`.

`Form_QueryUnload` fires before the `Form_Unload` where setting `Cancel` to any value other than 0 cancels the unload and `UnloadMode` indicates the cause of the unload event.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa445536(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

`Form_Unload` takes an integer that if set to any value other than 0, cancels the Unload.

> The Unload event procedure is where programmers usually put cleanup code. The Unload event fires after the QueryUnload event. The Unload event procedure takes a single parameter, the Cancel parameter. Unload's Cancel parameter works the same as QueryUnload's Cancel parameter.

> The Terminate event happens when the instance of the form has been completely unloaded and all the form's variables have been set to Nothing. The Terminate event happens only when you explicitly set the form to Nothing in your code during or after the Unload event procedure.

Source:  https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson6/p5.html

In your case, you probably want to put code into `Form_QueryUnload` or `Form_Unload` that checks if there are any other open forms.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If hasSubWindow = True Then
         MsgBox "You currently have active sub-window(s)", vbInformation, "Confirm"
        Cancel = 1
    End if
End Sub
```